# Variance returned by tf.nn.fused_batch_norm is different from tf.nn.moments

Tags: tensorflow

When I try to compare the variance output from tf.nn.fused_batch_norm and the one from tf.nn.moments I don't have the same values for the same inputs.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
tf.reset_default_graph()
inputs = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,4,4,1], dtype=tf.float32)
mean1, var1 = tf.nn.moments(inputs, [0,1,2])
_, mean2, var2 = tf.nn.fused_batch_norm( \
                inputs, scale=[1.], offset=[0.], \
                mean=None, variance=None, epsilon=1e-5, \
                data_format='NHWC', is_training=True, \
                name='reference')

val = np.random.rand(1,4,4,1)
mean3 = tf.reduce_mean(inputs, [0, 1, 2])
mean_sq3 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(inputs), [0, 1, 2])
var3 = mean_sq3 - tf.square(mean3)
var_eps1 = var3 + 1e-5
var_eps2 = var3 + np.sqrt(1e-5)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    mean_val, var_val = sess.run([mean1, var1], {inputs:val})
    print "tf.nn.moments: mean:", mean_val, "| var:", var_val
    mean_val, var_val = sess.run([mean2, var2], {inputs:val})
    print "tf.nn.fused_batch_norm: mean:", mean_val, "| var:", var_val
    mean_val, var_val, var_eps1_val, var_eps2_val = sess.run([mean3, var3, var_eps1, var_eps2], {inputs:val})
    print "customs: mean:", mean_val, "| var:", var_val, "| var + eps:", var_eps1_val, "| var + sqrt(eps):", var_eps2_val
```

You can see I tried to check if it has something to do with epsilon, but apparently not, as the script ran on GPU return this (it's random but the problem always occur):

```
tf.nn.moments: mean: [ 0.54445559] | var: [ 0.09011541]
tf.nn.fused_batch_norm: mean: [ 0.54445559] | var: [ 0.09612311]
customs: mean: [ 0.54445559] | var: [ 0.09011537] | var + eps: [ 0.09012537] | var + sqrt(eps): [ 0.09327765]
```

As you can see the variance from tf.nn.fused_batch_norm is higher than from tf.nn.moments (even after adding sqrt(epsilon))

Any clue why such difference ? (I don't think >5% is small, and it doesn't looks like a numerical precision problem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tf.nn.moments` is computing the sample variance, whereas `tf.nn.fused_batch_norm` is computing the unbiased variance estimator. The difference between the two is a factor `n/n-1`, where `n` is your sample size. The code applying this factor can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b183be3b4d62c1033bcb3c0fe2b24ba3eef86da7/tensorflow/core/kernels/fused_batch_norm_op.cc#L112).

Note however that while the returned variance is the unbiased estimated, the *saved* variance used for the moving average is the biased one.

In your example, your sample size is `4*4*1=16` and you will notice that `var2 = var1 * 16/15`.

When you take a much larger sample, you see that differences between `var1` and `var2` becomes smaller.

That would probably be worth mentioning in the documentation.